# Rails ActiveRecord - get all validations from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Is there a way to find all defined validations for a model. E.g :

```
class Temp < ActiveRecord::Base

     validate_uniqueness_of :name
     validate :some_method

     def some_method
        ...
     end
 end
```

When i try :

```
Temp.validators
```

It only finds the uniqueness validation, but not the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it by using :

```
Model._validate_callbacks.to_a.reject { |validation| validation.filter.to_s.starts_with?('validate_associated_records') }
```

The 'reject' is used to ignore some default validations.